# angular js allowing user to go to next tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to allow user to click button "next",then check a condition if it satisfies,then allow user to go to next page otherwise send a message 'you cannot view this page'.how to achieve this using angular 1??

Comment: Please be more specific in your question: what have you tried? How do you implement tabs? Etc.

Comment: @giraff: I have edited the question.When the user clicks the button a method is initiated from the controller in which there is a condition,if the condition satisfies allow him to go to to next page or else don't with an error message

Comment: check the ui-router library you can easily redirect user to another view after a click

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plunker also check the ui-router docs for more info

https://plnkr.co/edit/j3XVyHTtWex9Dpgr1tF0?p=preview

html

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs@1.0.5/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="helloworld.js"></script>
    <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold }</style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="helloworld" ng-controller="Ctrl">


    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body> 
</html>
```

js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var step1 = {
    name: 'step1',
    url: '/step1',
    template: `<h3>hello from step 1</h3><button ng-click="move('step2')">step 2</button>`
  }

  var step2 = {
    name: 'step2',
    url: '/step2',
    template: `<h3>hello from step 2</h3><button ng-click="move('step3')">step 3</button>`
  }
  var step3 = {
    name: 'step3',
    url: '/step3',
    template: '<h3>hello from step 3</h3>'
  }
  $stateProvider.state(step1);

  $stateProvider.state(step2);

  $stateProvider.state(step3);
}).
controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.move = function(move) {
    //check your condition here
    $state.transitionTo(move);
  }
  $scope.move('step1')
});
```

edited for comment